# How to use javascript to add or take content away from mobile / desktop

Tags: web

I want to display some html code if the user if on a desktop/laptop and if not display different data. here is my code

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
     if (screen.width <= 800) {
     <html>
     <p>You are on desktop , or a really big screen!</p>
     </html>
     } 
     </script>
```

Comment: why dont you use CSS media query? it would be easier

Comment: Could you get it to work please , I am going to make this site pretty simple and then work my way up , because I am only a teenager :p

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the effect you are after using media queries.
Here is a working **demo** -http://jsfiddle.net/se0fpegj/

move the "results" panel to make the `<p>You are on desktop , or a really big screen!</p>` element appear.

**Explanation:**

1. Apply the attribute - `class="see-me"` to the HTML element you want to media query to apply to, i.e.

```html
<p class="see-me">You are on desktop , or a really big screen!</p>
```

2. This block of CSS here

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    .see-me {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

is saying that this CSS "rule set" will only apply up to a screen width of 800px
Then, the "rule set" is saying, any elements which have a class of `see-me` should have the `display: none;` property (which, as the term implies - does not display the element)

**Update**
working demo using a table (without classes) - http://jsfiddle.net/738jqben/

Comment: That is useful thank you , but I am trying to add a table which means (as far as I know :P) you cannot add classes to it :P

Comment: Is there any way I can display html if the user is on desktop using my code?

Comment: Have **updated** my answer.  The media query applies at the ruleset level which includes anything that can be targeted with CSS (including HTML elements like tables). If the answer helped solve your problem, you can choose it as your accepted answer by clicking the big tick

Answer (score 0):

You can use [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) for this, bootstrap have css classes for this purpose, like visible-md that only shows the area in desktops.